# pydev syntax highlighting, comments vs string literals

Tags: pydev

Is there any way to get docstrings to highlight as a different color than string literals? Example:

```
def my_func():
    """This should be one color, these comments are used for documenting files"""
    return "this is a string literal, and should be another color"
```

For me, the syntax coloring for "bytes" seems to control both.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently.

The last release added support for different colors for bytes/unicode (i.e.: **u'str'** and **b'str'** will have different colors -- and the version without a **'u'** or **'b'** prefix is dependent on the grammar version you choose as it's different for Python 2 and 3), but docstrings are currently not differentiated (being bytes or unicode)...

This isn't completely straightforward in code terms (which was the reason it wasn't added in the last release, although I agree it's a nice feature to have, so, I may end up adding it in the future).